# Команда git revert

Tags: git, github, gitlab

В коммите “В” добавили лишнюю строку, сделали команду

```
git revert master~1
```

Ветка master выглядит так

> А<-В<-С<-D

что произойдет после команды?

```
git revert master~2
```

Правильно ли я понимаю - отменяет 2 последних коммита (С и D)

делает новый коммит E аналогичен B и соответственно D

> А<-В<-С<-D<-E

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем так. 
Согласно документации https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert
git revert master~2 отменит не 2 коммита, а третий коммит с конца. Число после ~ говорит об индексе коммита, который нужно отменить, а не о количестве коммитов.

Таким образом, в вашем примере, будет сначала отменён коммит B, а затем опять будет предпринята попытка отменить тот же самый коммит B, который уже был отменён. Поэтому Git не сможет сделать новый коммит Е, ведь ничего не поменялось - так и будет А-В-С-D, который фактически будет равен А-С.